# Maven 3.8.4 target produces exception stacks

Tags: java, maven

Until today I have used Maven 3.8.3. It worked fine.

Now, I have downloaded and unzipped Maven 3.8.4 and adapt the environment variables to this new path.
After restarting the console (and the complete system), "mvn -version" worked fine and shows the correct version of maven, but I am not able to build any project anymore.

After calling "mvn clean package" I receive hundreds of exception stacks; the last lines are:

```
...
constituent[0]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/conf/logging/
constituent[1]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/commons-cli-1.4.jar
constituent[2]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/commons-io-2.6.jar
constituent[3]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
constituent[4]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/guava-25.1-android.jar
constituent[5]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/guice-4.2.2-no_aop.jar
constituent[6]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/jansi-2.4.0.jar
constituent[7]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
constituent[8]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/javax.inject-1.jar
constituent[9]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.32.jar
constituent[10]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-artifact-3.8.4.jar
constituent[11]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-builder-support-3.8.4.jar
constituent[12]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-compat-3.8.4.jar
constituent[13]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-core-3.8.4.jar
constituent[14]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-embedder-3.8.4.jar
constituent[15]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-model-3.8.4.jar
constituent[16]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-model-builder-3.8.4.jar
constituent[17]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.8.4.jar
constituent[18]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.8.4.jar
constituent[19]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-resolver-api-1.6.3.jar
constituent[20]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.6.3.jar
constituent[21]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-resolver-impl-1.6.3.jar
constituent[22]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-resolver-provider-3.8.4.jar
constituent[23]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-resolver-spi-1.6.3.jar
constituent[24]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-resolver-transport-wagon-1.6.3.jar
constituent[25]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-settings-3.8.4.jar
constituent[26]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.8.4.jar
constituent[27]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-shared-utils-3.3.4.jar
constituent[28]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/maven-slf4j-provider-3.8.4.jar
constituent[29]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.5.jar
constituent[30]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.5.jar
constituent[31]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/plexus-cipher-2.0.jar
constituent[32]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/plexus-component-annotations-2.1.0.jar
constituent[33]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.26.jar
constituent[34]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-2.0.jar
constituent[35]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/plexus-utils-3.3.0.jar
constituent[36]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar
constituent[37]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/wagon-file-3.4.3.jar
constituent[38]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/wagon-http-3.4.3-shaded.jar
constituent[39]: file:/C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/lib/wagon-provider-api-3.4.3.jar
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/aether/util/graph/visitor/PreorderNodeListGenerator
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getDeclaredMethods(InjectionPoint.java:766)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:683)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:378)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:182)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:661)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:617)
...
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:691)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.aether.util.graph.visitor.PreorderNodeListGenerator
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        ... 135 more
```

The paths to 3.8.3 and 3.8.4 look exactly the same. The lib-directory including the jar-files inside of the maven directories exists in both cases. Can somebody give me any advice what I am doing wrong here?

Advice: I am not using "eclipse" as an IDE here, I try to build the project on cmd.

I am using the following Java:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_312"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_312-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.312-b07, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Can write which Env variables you have changed/adapted? You only need one the location in the PATH variable no other env variable is needed nor useful...

Comment: There were M2_HOME and PATH. In both cases I just adapt 3.8.3 to 3.8.4. Then I have restartet cmd and the complete system

Comment: First I would suggest to remove `M2_HOME` because only the `C:/mypath/apache-maven-3.8.4/bin` is needed in your PATH. Second. Where have you downloaded apache Maven from? Have you checked the Hashes.. ? Can you check via `SET M` which variables are set in the console?

Comment: Also first check only `mvn --version` ...and second show the project on which you have checked the execution in particular more of the output logging...because it looks like issues with plugins(old?)

Comment: "mvn -version" works fine. It shows 3.8.4. The SHA512 is correct, I have downloaded it from the officiel maven homepage. If I adapt the env variable back to 3.8.3 everything works fine again.

Comment: Ok please show more output of the build...because I suppose that's an issue with a plugin...

Comment: You can try to remove .m2 folder and build it again. It may take time but it should fix the issue if there's any corrupted jar in your .m2 folder.
If you've added maven-compiler-plugin to your pom.xml file, you should make sure that the property value for <version> should be 3.9.0 or at least 3.8.1.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Dont know why, but suddenly it seems to work. After I did a clean reinstall of Java, an removed the m2-dir. Maybe something stupid was cached and has blocked the package target.

Comment: Deleting .m2 did not work. However `dnf remove maven*` + `dnf install maven` did